# how to integrate dropwizard metrics for monitoring cassandra database

Tags: cassandra, dropwizard, metrics, health-monitoring

I want to monitor health of my cassandra cluster. And got to know about dropwizard metrics, but dont know how to integrate dropwizard metrics with my cassandra cluster to monitor it.
For this I want to use JMX as metrics reporter,graphite as metrics collector and Grafana as visualization GUI
can anyone help me here please.

Comment: please extend your question with more information - how do you want to collect metrics, what system to use to store them, etc. - without this information it's very hard to provide an answer

Comment: @AlexOtt : I want to use JMX as metrics reporter,graphite as metrics collector and Grafana as visualization GUI

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra itself uses dropwizard Metrics and has a pluggable reporting interface since 2.0.2 ([announcement post](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/pluggable-metrics-reporting-in-cassandra-2-0-2)). ['Monitoring Apache Cassandra Metrics With Graphite and Grafana'](https://blog.pythian.com/monitoring-apache-cassandra-metrics-graphite-grafana/) gives a good overview on how to configure Cassandra to report metrics to graphite:

> 1). Download Graphite metrics reporter jar file
>
> 2). Put the downloaded jar file in Cassandra library folder, e.g. /usr/share/cassandra/lib/ (the default Cassandra library folder under packaged installation on Ubuntu 14.0.4)
>
> 3). Create a metrics reporter configuration file (e.g. metrics_reporter_graphite.yaml) and put it under the same folder as cassandra.yaml file, e.g. /etc/cassandra/ (the default Cassandra configuration folder under packaged installation on Ubuntu 14.0.4).

```
graphite:
  -
    period: 30
    timeunit: 'SECONDS'
    prefix: 'cassandra-clustername-node1'
    hosts:
     - host: 'localhost'
       port: 2003
    predicate:
      color: 'white'
      useQualifiedName: true
      patterns:
        - '^org.apache.cassandra.+'
        - '^jvm.+'
```

> 4). Modify cassandra-env.sh file to include the following JVM option:

```
METRICS_REPORTER_CFG="metrics_reporter_graphite.yaml"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.metricsReporterConfigFile=$METRICS_REPORTER_CFG"
```

> 5). Restart Cassandra service

Comment: i'm using MX4J as metrics reporter to graphite.but dont know how to configure MX4J to report metrics to graphite.

Comment: mx4j isnt a metrics reporter, it just exposes JMX as HTTP, you would need another tool to then fetch http and report to graphite. Theres already a direct metrics to graphite reporter Andy describes above